# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Back button can't be pressed

Tags: java, android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I am doing this for exit an application using **Android UIAutomator**.

```
assertTrue("Back button can't be pressed", getUiDevice().pressBack());

assertTrue("Back button can't be pressed", getUiDevice().pressBack());   // This line will giving exception.
```

My application will exit when we press *two times back button* that's why i am calling it twice.

But

Then it will give me exception.

But when i'm doing it manually back twice it will work perfectly.

**Exception is:**

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Back button can't be pressed
        at com.android.jdsu.automation.youtube.YoutubeUiTest.exitApplicaion(Yout
ubeUiTest.java:487)
        at com.android.jdsu.automation.youtube.YoutubeUiTest.testYouTube(Youtube
UiTest.java:208)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAuto
matorTestRunner.java:160)
        at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutoma
torTestRunner.java:96)
        at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.ja
va:91)
        at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testYouTube
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.android.jdsu.automation.youtube.YoutubeUiTest
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stack=junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Back button
can't be pressed
        at com.android.jdsu.automation.youtube.YoutubeUiTest.exitApplicaion(Yout
ubeUiTest.java:487)
        at com.android.jdsu.automation.youtube.YoutubeUiTest.testYouTube(Youtube
UiTest.java:208)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAuto
matorTestRunner.java:160)
        at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutoma
torTestRunner.java:96)
        at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.ja
va:91)
        at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya I too experienced same problem, but didn't get why this happens.
I got it working by using as follows:

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance();
device.pressMenu();
```

This is working fine for me.
Else you can also use `keyevent` as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/input keyevent 82");
```

Comment: btw, "back" (as mentioned in OP) is `/system/bin/input keyevent 4` (constant from `android.view.KeyEvent#KEYCODE_BACK`)

Answer (score 1):

`assertTrue("Back button can't be pressed", getUiDevice().pressBack());`

It will return false if UI has not changed after `pressBack()`, if current is in home view it will return false after `getUiDevice().pressBack());`

Comment: martin, I can see the effect of `pressBack()`, the activity on top closed and another one activated. I still get `false` as result.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting one:
https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/blob/ad4aa239aa8352553325c800829202d960030d25/bootstrap/src/io/appium/android/bootstrap/handler/PressBack.java#L43

Based on this we can't trust `UIDevice.pressBack()`, at least if we trust Appium.

It's curious though that it works most of the time and actually returns true. In my empirical experience, it works fine with Intent Chooser, Google Drive, Google Play Store, but not with Device Settings on API 19. So so far I have this, which is more strict that Appium's solution:

```
    @RequiresApi(VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public static void pressBackExternal() {
        UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT == VERSION_CODES.KITKAT
                && "com.android.settings".equals(device.getCurrentPackageName())) {
            // fails because pressBack sometimes returns false even though the Settings is closed.
            device.pressBack();
        } else {
            assertTrue("expected to press Back button", device.pressBack());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, did you try adding wait time between two calls. Your application might need some time to reload last activity. Add at least 500ms or 1s of wait time.

Comment: Yes i have also use `Thread.sleep(3000)` between two call but still i t will giving same exception.

Comment: Shivam, where would you put the sleep? The problem is that `pressBack()` returns false. Putting it before would have no effect, because the back button has not been pressed yet, so there's nothing to wait for. Putting it after is too late, because the button has been already pressed and process; it has been decided that the return value is false.